# Spring security default-target-url does not work

Tags: java, spring-security

I am facing problem with `default-target-url` option in configuration of Spring security. It always redirects to the root context of my application when I login successfully.

Here is the configuration file snippet:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.html"
                         login-processing-url="/login_check"
                         default-target-url="/test111111.html"
                         always-use-default-target="true"
                         authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=true"
                         authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler"/>
```

And I use the Spring MVC as my MVC framework.

Comment: Are you using any MVC framework here like Spring MVC?

Comment: Yes, I use the SpringMVC, Is there any problem?

Comment: Please check out my answer, accept if resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lets understand your scenario from the simplest prospective. You are
>   using Spring MVC in your web-project. I am assuming you have a
>   `requestHandler` mapped to `root` `context`, then whenever I hit an
>   invalid URL like `test111111.html` it will redirect to the `home page`.

The point here is to make `default-target-url="/test111111.html"` work, you need to have a `Spring MVC requestHandler` to handle request `/test111111.html`.

Like I said, you need to have a proper request handler like:

```
@Controller
public class DurClass {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/defaultTarget", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String defaultTarget(Model model) {

        return "defaultTarget.html";
   }
}


<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.html"
                         login-processing-url="/login_check"
                         default-target-url="/defaultTarget"
                         always-use-default-target="true"
                         authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=true"
                         authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler"/>
```